# Copy a file to many folders

Tags: batch-file, architecture, copy, directory

Thank you for taking the time to help me with my batch problem... So here it goes:
I have a file with a specific version of a specific program. Lets call it `Prog`.
So, the good version of `PROG` is in a folder in `C:\Users`, for example. The architecture of
the folders is: `C:\users\%department%\%user%`. I would like to have a batch file that will copy `PROG.exe` in the `C:\Users`, in every single folders. There are about 5 departments that contains many users. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly is the original `prog.exe` you want to copy? And exactly what folders are you wanting to copy it to?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help... The way it works is, prog.exe is in C:\users\new. and i would like it to be copied in EVERY folders AND subfolders in C:\users\. THere are about 5 departments. so it goes like 'C:\users\department1\%users%' 'C:\Users\department2\%users%'

Comment: So you want it copied to `C:\users\department1` as well as `C:\users\department1\%users%`, etc? And wouldn't you rather have a shortcut to the `exe` rather than making duplicate copies of the `exe`?

Comment: This is the way the application works... This EXE is used by many users, since there is a batch file that starts it for every users when they log on. so if we refer to only 1 exe, it will only work for one user... And i want it to be copied only in C:\Users\Department1\%users%, C:\users\Department2\%users%,C:\users\Department3\%users% C:\users\Department4\%users%, C:\users\Department5\%users%. Hope it is better explained that way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /d %i in (*) do for /d %j in (%i\*) do copy prog.exe %j
```

put this in C:\users. it will copy it to every sub dir of every sub dir of C:\users

Comment: Hi, could you please explain (i am quite new to this, and i'd like to understand, not just make it work) Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: the for /d says to match directories with the wildcard, not files. the first one matches all directories in the current dir. if you want to match only files starting with Department, replace the contents of the first set of parenthesis with "Department*" the second for take all dirs in each dir in C:\users, and copies prog .exe to it. it does this by taking each dir in the first dir found and setting %j to its path. it then does this for the second value of %i and so on. to use this in a batch file, be sure to use double %'s for all the %'s

Comment: From the op's comments to his original post, it looks like he only wants the `exe` copied to the `%user%` folders. So the `for` will need to be modified to meet that requirement.

Comment: replace the %i\* with "%i\%user%" if it should only be copied to that dir.